# C++ Neural Network Library

Tags: c++, api, neural-network

I'm looking for a Neural Network library, which can be used commercial and ist accessible for c++.

It should contain the following:

1. fast
2. convolutional networks
3. multiple learining algorithms(rprop...)
4. c++ binding (I want to create c++ applications and use the network as a libary)

I spend the last week looking but I was not able to find one. Some of the things I had a look at:

1. tensorflow (but 90% of the functions are only for python)
2. fastnn (no convolutional networks)
3. opennn (seems outdated, many erros while building vs2015)
4. and many more(opencv ...)

I also had a quick look at eblearn, which seems to be quite restrictive, and convnet which might be slow and have some licence problems.

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok for you to use a Microsoft/.NET solution have a look at CNTK (Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/

> The Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit - CNTK - is a unified deep-learning toolkit by Microsoft.

...

> CNTK can be included as a library in your Python, C#, or **C++** programs, or used as a standalone machine learning tool through its own model description language (BrainScript).

...

> CNTK supports 64-bit Linux or 64-bit Windows operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering using GPU(s) for simulating your neural networks, you should consider [nVIDIA's cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn).

They have a [webina](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2015/webinar/gtc-express-cuDNN-larry-brown.mp4)r regarding how to use it. Using CUDA is natively done in C++, and CUDA GPU kernel code per se is written in a large subset of C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at Caffe

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe

There is a Linux and Windows version.

The windows version I think is maintained my Microsoft.
I used it projects in the past and it seemed to function perfectly for me.

The community is big and there is a decent amount of examples/info on it.
It supports cuDNN so thats a plus as well.